# how to creat a rss feed from an internet website with android?

Tags: java, android, rss, feed

i wanted to do an application which use a rss feed from the web, and i wanna know if someone have a tutorial somewhere or could just explain to me how to do it. (I started coding in android like two months ago)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html

That's a nice tutorial on parsing XML with the Android APIs, and it also includes an example feed parser.